# Point free version for readMaybe

Tags: haskell, monads, pointfree

I want to write a function to read an `Int` without `do` notation. It works (see below), but I was wondering if it the bit around `readMaybe` can be written in point free form (or cleaned up a bit in some other way)?

```
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= (\x -> return $ (readMaybe x :: Maybe Int)) >>= print
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Replace the lambda with its pointfree equivalent:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= return . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) >>= print
```

Step 2: Replace `m >>= return . f` with `f <$> m`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) <$> getLine >>= print
```

Step 3: Replace `f <$> m >>= g` with `m >>= g . f`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= print . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int)
```

Step 4: Use a type application instead of writing out a long, awkward type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= print . readMaybe @Int
```

---

As an alternative to using `<$>` in steps 2 and 3, you can accomplish the same with just the monad laws, like this (picking up after step 1):

Replace `m >>= f >>= g` with `m >>= \x -> f x >>= g` (associativity):

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= \x -> (return . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int)) x >>= print
```

Simplify the `.` away:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= \x -> return ((readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) x) >>= print
```

Replace `return x >>= f` with `f x` (left identity):

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= \x -> print ((readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) x)
```

Now just replace that new lambda with its pointfree equivalent, and you end up in the exact same place as step 3.

Comment: This is pretty cool, thank you! I really wanted to keep the structure in the form of `get input >>= parse >>= something >>= something >>= print`, any thoughts how i can simplify `(\x -> return $ (readMaybe x :: Maybe Int))` in that context?

Comment: @zoran119 You could do `getLine >>= return . readMaybe @Int >>= print` then.

Comment: Perfect! And just to clarify, there is no way to write `return . readMaybe :: Maybe Int` point free without `TypeApplications`? The `:: Maybe Int` bit gets "in the way"? (I'm happy writing the full type out in my example in the question, it is the `\x ->` that I would like to remove)

Comment: @zoran119 You could replace `readMaybe @Int` with `(readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int)` if you want to get rid of the type application.

Comment: Oh wow! `getLine >>= return . (readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int) >>= print` works! I really need to understand this black magic here... Why does `String ->` part of the signature make things work??? I was under impression that `readMaybe` only "took" the "destination" type for what it was going to try to put the input into.

Comment: @zoran119 That's true of `readMaybe x`, but I didn't specify the type of that. I specified the type of just `readMaybe`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you so much for your explanations!

Comment: @zoran119, you should learn about `>=>` and `<=<` in `Control.Monad`. They're really nice for point-free monadic stuff.